# Gentoo Linux: emerge installs several versions of portages

Tags: linux, gentoo

I'm a beginner in Gentoo Linux. Just have been installed Calculate.

I want to install Ruby. But when I call `emerge -av dev-lang/ruby` it installs 1.8.7 AND 1.9.3 AND 2.0.0. Why??

Ok. When I specify a version: `emerge -av =dev-lang/ruby-1.9.3_p484` - it's all the same.

But when I try to install 1.8.7, it installs 1.8.7 ONLY.

Why??? And how can I install 1.9.3 only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These scary things are named slots. These versions "can" stay in same system and you're installing "ruby" , not a specific version.

Ruby 1.9 might call some dependencies which is looking for targets, I guess you should try adding this line on /etc/portage/make.conf :

> RUBY_TARGETS="ruby19"